# jenkins VS openldap: authentication fails but lookup ok

Tags: jenkins, ldap, openldap

I searched for my issue and found quite the same [here](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Jenkins-LDAP-Query-td4418917.html) with no answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009996/configure-jenkins-with-ldap) does no help, neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940853/jenkins-openldap-authentication-not-working), so I ask here.

I have an openldap

> Version
>
> (version slapd  (Ubuntu) (May 22 2018 13:54:12) $
>     buildd@bos02-arm64-019:/build/openldap-AktVWV/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/servers/slapd)

on an odroid hc1 working fine (I can authenticate on some VM using PAM_ldap) and a jenkins (version 2.138) on my local machine working fine as well.

Issue comes in when I configure jenkins to use ldap to authenticate users.
When testing the settings with the "Test ldap settings" button, lookup is ok

> Lookup User lookup: successful User ID: test User Dn:
>   "cn=test+gidNumber=5556+givenName=test+homeDirectory=/home/test+loginShell=/bin/bash+sn=test+uid=test,ou=users",dc=home,dc=local
>   User Display Name: test User email: test@home.local LDAP Group
>   membership: jenkins LDAP Group lookup: successful (1 group)

but login fails and a lockout warning message is displayed

> The user "test" will be unable to login with the supplied password. If
>   this is your own account this would mean you would be locked out! Are
>   you sure you want to save this configuration?

Here is the ldap config in jenkins:

```
Server: ldap://192.168.1.106
root DN: dc=home,dc=local
User search filter: uid={0}
Group membership: Search for LDAP groups containing user
Manager DN: cn=admin,dc=home,dc=local
Manager Password: ••••••••••
Display Name LDAP attribute: uid
Email Address LDAP attribute: mail
```

ldap's log shows this when jenkins login fails:

> slapd[844]: conn=1254 op=0 do_bind: invalid dn
>   ("cn=test+gidNumber=5556+givenName=test+homeDirectory=/home/test+loginShell=/bin/bash+sn=test+uid=test,ou=users",dc=home,dc=local)

note the double quote after ou=users. Does it seem like a concatination issue?

the dn computed by jenkins and sent to openldap is invalid and should be

```
("cn=test+gidNumber=5556+givenName=test+homeDirectory=/home/test+loginShell=/bin/bash+sn=test+uid=test,ou=users,dc=home,dc=local")
```

If I use Apache Directory Studio and issue the search using the invalid dn, it fails (obviously) and if I search using the fixed dn, the search returns the expected record.

Openldap does not allow anonymous binding, hence admin credentials in jenkins config.

I tried to add/remove root dn (test fails if missing), search base (test fails  if filled or not), search group (same).

I'm kindda out of ideas to sort this up.

I must be missing something.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: add test user ldif

```
dn: cn=test+gidNumber=5556+givenName=test+homeDirectory=/home/test+loginShel
 l=/bin/bash+sn=test+uid=test,ou=users,dc=home,dc=local
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: test
gidNumber: 5556
homeDirectory: /home/test
sn: test
uid: test
uidNumber: 5556
userPassword:: e1NTSEF9aCtmbmhraXVJSXp1MmRETUY4Zm4wK3NpYzVrUEF6VXJmWUhKUmc9P
 Q==
givenName: test
loginShell: /bin/bash
mail: test@home.local
```

Edit2: I have an install of free artifactory. I was able to add ldap settings and test authentication with the same test user with success and without any change in ldap configuration or tree.

Answer (score 0):

Been having the same issue until I found the password hash that works is the SSHA with jenkins.

Comment: I'll give it a try as soon as I have time for that and let you know.